# Why can't I type in letters in the USERNAME field in drupal 7 user account page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, user-accounts, user-account-control

I am trying to login to my Drupal 7 website.
Not sure why but when I try to type in my username "admin" in the username field it won't type anything at all. When I try to type in numbers though "4214214" it lets me type it in.

Anyone have this issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the password form <input> type ? Check whether any *hook_form_alter* modifies your login form.

Comment: Try using default drupal theme instead of your custom.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case if in Drupal you define an integer field and in form you type text in integer field Drupal by default wont disable typing but after submit you will get error message
So you have to check your any javascript file who disable text typing